# reaching particular co-ordinate in projectile motion?

Tags: iphone, physics

As I wanted to animate an image in projectile motion, 
My code is as follows, but it did not reach the target and give projectile animation, any help please?

```
-(void)timeLine
{

dTime += 0.1;


.................


double s_x =   inVel * cos(angle1)  ; // the X speed
double s_y =   inVel * sin(angle1) ;  // the Y speed


NSLog(@"sx = %i",s_x);

NSLog(@"sy = %i",s_y);


x =   oX + (s_x * dTime);
y =   oY + ( ( s_y * dTime) - (0.5 * 9.8 * dTime * dTime));

NSLog(@"x = %i",x);

NSLog(@"y = %i",y);

imageViewForAnimation.x += x;
imageViewForAnimation.y -= y;
}
```

Comment: Have you taken into account that you do not start at the origin, or is `oX=oY=0`?

Comment: originX and originY are not equal to zero..

Comment: Then you have to include them also in your calculation of `v_x` and `v_y` by replacing `x` with `(x-oX)` and `y` with `(y-oY)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageViewForAnimation.x += x;
imageViewForAnimation.y -= y;
```

These lines don't seem right to me. You are calculating the actual x and y each time, not the difference moved since the last time. I'm also uncertain why one was being added and one was being subtracted, but that's beside the point. Basically, try changing the lines to

```
imageViewForAnimation.x = x;
imageViewForAnimation.y = y;
```

Also, you're doing some calculations over and over which only need to be done once. v_x == s_x (or it should within floating point error) as well as v_y == s_y. You only need to calculate v_x and V_y once beforehand rather than calculating them every time you update the coordinates.